# Is it possible to determine if data was encrypted by a specific public key?

Tags: encryption, provable-security

If the prover provides a block of data and a public key. The provided data is supposedly ciphertext that was encrypted using the provided public key. Is there a way to prove that the provided data has infact been encrypted using that specific public key?

The verifier does not have access in any way to the plaintext data or the private key. However, the prover does have access to the plaintext data and private key, and can provide additional information to assist in proving, as long as zero knowledge of the plaintext data and private key are exposed to the verifier.

Update:
Based on the current responses, it seems unlikely that the verifier would be able to prove or disprove the claim by the prover using only the provided data and public key. However, the question still remains if this could be accomplished using some form of additional proof data, possibly in conjuction with a zero knowledge based algorithm.

Comment: Any specific schemes you want us to refer to? The schemes in RSA/PKCS#1 for instance? I know one way in which it is possible to show that something was *not* encrypted with a specific key in certain conditions, but usually the schemes are randomized enough, so you can never be certain who encrypted it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes There isn't really any specific scheme, but I do slightly favor anything that is believed to be post-quantum secure and has a public key size that is 5KiB or smaller.

Comment: Is the "piece of data" the alleged-ciphertext or the plaintext? ​ (In the latter case, presumably there's an [encapsulation](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/id-cca-mac.pdf) of the plaintext.) ​ Is [the "you" who does "not have access in any way to the decrypted data or the private key"] the prover or the verifier? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: You may be interested in the paper [Key-Privacy in Public-Key Encryption](http://iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480568.pdf)

Comment: @RickyDemer The prover submits data and a public key. The data is claimed to be ciphertext which has been encrypted using the provided public key. The verifier must determine if the claim is true or false. The claim is true if the provided data has been encrypted using the provided public key. The verifier does not have access in any way to the plaintext, or the private key. The prover does have access to the plaintext and private key. The prover can provide additional data to the verifier to assist with proving as long as it gives zero knowledge about the plaintext data and private key.

Comment: @EllaRose Thanks for the paper. It's a bit over my head, but from what I was able to gather, proving the ciphertext was encrypted using a specific public key is either impossible, or very difficult if the scheme used is vulnerable to an attack. This being the case, proof in a straightforward manner would necessitate some additional data to be provided.

Answer (score 3):

**This depends on the scheme that is being used.**

*In the case of a scheme that behaves like a random oracle:* We could assume that the scheme that is used behaves as a *random oracle*, and that we are to infer by the ciphertext that some specific key was used. This would imply that we *could* actually get *some* information about the key, by knowing only the ciphertext (and not the plaintext). Namely if a specific key was used to encrypt the plaintext. This would however violate the assumption that the scheme behaves like a random oracle. So **in the case of a random oracle** the answer would be **no**.